# Promise.all() with loop and store the result to a JSON object in Javascript concurrently

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I want to loop through a list and make the calls concurrently instead of making it sequentially and store the result in a JSON Object.

```
var keys = ["1", "2", "10", "11", "12", "19", "20"];

for (const key of keys) {
            JSON_OBJECT[key] = await ns_bundle.get(key, "json")
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve this using Promise.all().

I have gone through some implementation, but this way I have to unnecessarily write too many lines of code.

```
const JSON_OBJECT = {}
const [JSON_OBJECT.a, JSON_OBJECT.b] = await Promise.all([first(a), second(b)])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the body of the `for` loop into an async `.map` callback:

```
await Promise.all(
  keys.map(async key => {
    JSON_OBJECT[key] = await ns_bundle.get(key, "json");
  })
);
```

Can also achieve it with `.then`, but it's uglier:

```
await Promise.all(
  keys.map(
    key => ns_bundle.get(key, "json")
      .then((result) => {
        JSON_OBJECT[key] = result;
      })
  )
);
```

Comment: Also note that [there's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). If you have an object or array, then you have an object or array, full stop. JSON format is a *method of representing an object in a string*, like `const myJSON = '{"foo":"bar"}'`. If there are no strings, serialization, or deserialization involved, then JSON is not involved either. Better to use a more appropriate variable name than `JSON_OBJECT`.

Comment: That's not really a fair comparison in your presentation of the two code blocks because you formatted the 2nd code block verbosely (with lots of extra lines) and the 1st code block succinctly (with minimal lines).  Format them similarly and there won't be much difference between the two.